# how to fix when onpress then cart is rerender whole component in react native

Tags: react-native

I would share to two files which are index.js and supply.js (child component from index.js). this is for the pos app that has gas stations and tools for cars. tracking data from the users. However, after adding the tool's number it is so slow to show up from count. Example: count is 0 to increase one then almost spent three seconds. The fixing bug is for just added to show immediately and also total amount will show which can controlled from the amount, set amount.

index.js--->

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, FlatList, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import apiSupplies from '../../../../api/supplies.api'
import actions from '../../../../store/actions'
import SupplyItem from './supply'

const Supplies = ({ mainState, setSupplyCart, navigation, setAmountToPay }) => {
  const { dark } = useTheme();
  const [ cart, setCart ] = useState(new Map())
  const [ supplies, setSupplies ] = useState([])
  const [ amount, setAmount ] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const newAmount = Array.from(cart.keys()).reduce((acc, curr) => acc + cart.get(curr).count * cart.get(curr).supply.price, 0)
    setAmount(newAmount);
  }, [cart])

  const fetch = async () => {
    console.log(`[FETCH] ${JSON.stringify(await apiSupplies.getList())}`)
    const {data: { data: {supplies: res} }} = await apiSupplies.getList();
    setSupplies(res);
  }

  const onBuy = async () => {
    const c = Array.from(cart.keys()).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc.push(cart.get(curr));
      return acc
    }, []);
    setSupplyCart(c);
    setAmountToPay(amount)
    navigation.navigate('bonus')
  }

  useEffect(() => {fetch();}, [])

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignContent: 'center',
    },
    button: {
      backgroundColor: '#147EFB',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      borderRadius: 8,
      padding: 8
    },
    buttonText: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      color: dark ? '#fff' : '#ddd'
    },
    totalText: {
      color: dark ? '#fff' : '#ddd',
      marginBottom: 8
    }
  })

  return (<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={supplies}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <SupplyItem item={item} onQuantityChange={(item, count, type) => {
        setCart(new Map(cart.set(item.code, {supply: item, count})));
      }
      } />}
      numColumns={2}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
    />
    <View style={{ padding: 28 }}>
      <Text style={styles.totalText}>Нийт дүн: {String(amount ?? 0).replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',') }</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onBuy}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
          Худалдан авах
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </SafeAreaView>)
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  mainState: state.main,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setSupplyCart: (value) => dispatch(actions.setCart(value)),
  reset: () => dispatch(actions.reset()),
  setAmountToPay: (payload) => dispatch(actions.setAmountToPay(payload)),
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Supplies)
```

and the supply.js --->

```
  import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native'
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native'
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'

const SupplyItem = ({ item, onQuantityChange }) => {
  const { imageUrl, code, quantity, name, price } = item
  const { dark } = useTheme()
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  const TRASHOLD_M = 10
  const TRASHOLD_F = 5

  const quantityOpt = quantity > TRASHOLD_M 
  ? {color: '#ddd', title: 'Олон'} 
  : quantity > TRASHOLD_F 
    ? {color: '#FFFF33', title: 'Бага'} 
    : {color: '#DC143C', title: 'Цөөхөн'}

  const styles = {
    imageThumbnail: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
    itemCard: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      margin: 6,
      alignContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      backgroundColor: dark ? '#11131B' : '#ddd',
      borderRadius: 12,
    },
    nameText: {
      color: dark ? '#fff' : '#111',
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    priceText: {
      color: dark ? '#fff' : '#111',
      textAlign: 'center',
    },
    quantityText: {
      color: quantityOpt.color,
      textAlign: 'center',
      paddingBottom: 8,
    },
    quantityTextInput: {
      backgroundColor: '#11131B',
      height: 30,
      padding: 4,
      textAlign: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      color: '#ddd'
    },
    button: {
      backgroundColor: '#147EFB',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
    },
    buttonText: {
      color: '#fff',
      textAlign: 'center',
      fontWeight: '900', 
      fontSize: 20
    }
  }

  function updateCount(count, type) {
    setCount(count);
    (async () => onQuantityChange(item, count, type))()
  }

  return <View style={styles.itemCard}>
    <Image style={styles.imageThumbnail} source={{ uri: imageUrl }} width={100} height={100} />
    <Text style={styles.nameText} >{name}</Text>
    <Text style={styles.priceText} > Үнэ: {price}{'₮'}</Text>
    {/* <Text style={styles.quantityText} > Үлдсэн тоо: {quantityOpt.title} </Text> */}
    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ ...styles.button, borderTopLeftRadius: 10, borderBottomLeftRadius: 10 }}
        onPress={() => { 
          let newCnt = Number(count) - 1
          if (newCnt < 0) newCnt = 0
          updateCount(newCnt, 'remove'); 
        }}
      >
        <MaterialIcons 
          name='remove'
          style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
          size={26}
          color={ '#fff' }
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text style={{...styles.quantityTextInput, marginHorizontal: 8}}>
        {count}
      </Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ ...styles.button, borderTopRightRadius: 10, borderBottomRightRadius: 10 }}
        onPress={() => { 
          let newCnt = Number(count) + 1
          if (newCnt > quantity) newCnt = quantity
          updateCount(newCnt, 'add'); 
        }}
      >
        <MaterialIcons 
          name='add'
          style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
          size={26}
          color={ '#fff' }
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
}

export default SupplyItem
```

So what I want is to fix uneccesary render that is inside the index.js.

hint (here is the unnecessarily rendering):

```
   <FlatList
  data={supplies}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <SupplyItem item={item} onQuantityChange={(item, count, type) => {
    setCart(new Map(cart.set(item.code, {supply: item, count})));
  }
  } />}
  numColumns={2}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
/>
```